# Paypal express checkout does not display properly in firefox

Tags: php, express, paypal, express-checkout

I've created an e-commerce website in PHP and am using the paypal express checkout API. It's currently in sandbox mode and has been working fine up until today. I've visited the website today and checked it on the latest version of firefox but the actual express checkout website does not display properly.

A link to the shop is http://www.voodoo-london.com/index-m.php. I've also included a screenshot of the express checkout looking all screwy. !

http://www.voodoo-london.com/ss.png

Really have no idea how to resolve this...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the stylesheet simply failed to load.  I see that on PayPal's servers sometimes, even the live ones, but it's pretty rare.  Is this continuing to happen to you consistently?  You might try clearing the cache/cookies in your Firefox browser to see if that resolves it.

Comment: Hello andrew, thanks for you're comments. This is what i thought, maybe it's something to do with the network i'm on at work as well?

Comment: Yep tried everything. Absolutely nothing works. Thinking it might be to do with Firefox itself...

Comment: What version of FireFox?  I just installed the latest version and I'm not having troubles with PayPal's sandbox at all.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla fixed the bug in this latest version.

Case closed